# Mouse events not working in Vim on Debian?

Tags: vim, tmux, tilda

If I click on a line, I can see "19m" or "18m" etc. show up in the bottom right of the screen. If I scroll, nothing happens, but shift+click&drag works.

```
set encoding=utf8                                                                                    
set ttym=xterm2
set mouse=a
```

I've tried a few variations of the above but nothing looks different.

I'm using a config file that worked on Ubuntu, so this change is odd.

I'm using the [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda) terminal emulator, with tmux inside, to interact with vim. Specifically, `tmux -2` wrapped around zsh running vim.

bash `TERM=mlterm`, tmux/zsh `TERM=xterm-256color`

Comment: Hey John, please don't add such important information to the comments alone! Instead, in general, add them to your question by editing it, please! I've done that for you in this case :)

Comment: Can you include the output of `echo $TERM` in your terminal emulator both outside of tmux and within tmux?  That will help us figure out if that's related to your problem (as I suspect it might be).

Comment: @bk2204 From bash, mlterm. From zsh & tmux+zsh, xterm-256color. I definitely want 256-color support if possible.

Comment: @bk2204 Bounty is active if you have a minute

Comment: Does it work if you set `TERM=tmux-256color` or `TERM=screen-256color` in tmux?  `xterm-256color` is not correct for inside of tmux.

Comment: @bk2204 That did it. The way it was defined before worked on linux lite, kind of a mystery to me now. The bounty is yours, thank you, please just write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TERM` environment variable controls what character sequences are sent and received by programs and the proper value depends on the terminal emulator.  Inside tmux, you generally want one of the `tmux-*` or `screen-*` values, preferably the former.  If you change to the correct terminal type, this will probably work as expected.

In most cases, `tmux-direct` is the most featureful (it supports true colour), but not all systems support it.  `tmux-256color` is an option on many modern systems, and you can also use `screen-256color` in a pinch.  To verify whether a terminal definition is available on your system, you can run `infocmp tmux-direct` (or whatever value you like) and that will either print the definition (if it's available) or a message that it's not available.

Note that if you SSH into older machines, it may be better to set one of the 256-colour modes instead of `tmux-direct` since the `TERM` setting is copied over by default and having a value that doesn't exist on the machine can break most terminal-using programs, including your shell.

To set the default terminal type in tmux, you can use `set -g default-terminal tmux-256color` in `~/.tmux.conf`.